# How to split a large json file based on which time of day each entry was created?

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

I have a 10GB JSON file that I need to split into two files: One with all entries between 6pm and 6am, and one with all entries between 6am and 6pm.

I have the following code that uses Pandas between_time function, which works on smaller datasets, but is incredibly memory inefficient to the point where my 10GB JSON file cannot fit into memory:

```py
from pandas import read_json,to_datetime

def main():

    full_df = read_json('data.json')

    full_df['created_at'] = full_df['created_at'].astype(str).str[:-6] #strip timezone
    full_df['created_at'] = full_df['created_at'].apply(to_datetime)

    full_df = full_df.set_index('created_at')

    full_df.between_time('18:00', '6:00', True, False).reset_index().drop(columns="created_at").to_json('night.json',orient='records')
    full_df.between_time('6:00', '18:00', True, False).reset_index().drop(columns="created_at").to_json('day.json',orient='records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's an example of my data:

```
{"field1":3253235,"field2":424444,"created_at":"2019-11-11 08:51:44.0910000 +00:00"}
```

Is there a simpler/more efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `object_hook` argument of the `load` function like this:

```
def callback(obj):
    ct = obj['created_at']
    t = datetime.strptime(ct, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    fname = 'night.json' if t.hour >= 18 else 'day.json'

    with open(fname, "a") as f:
        if f.tell() == 0:
            f.write('[')
        else:
            f.write(',')
        f.write(json.dumps(obj))

    return {}

json.load(f, object_hook=callback)
with open("night.json", "a") as f:
    f.write(']')
with open("day.json", "a") as f:
    f.write(']')
```